# Quais as principais diferenças entre Kotlin e Java?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, kotlin

Há tempos tomei conhecimento da existência da linguagem Kotlin. Sei que necessita da JVM para correr e que é completamente interoperável com Java.

Na altura não lhe dei muita atenção mas agora com a possibilidade do Android Studio lhe vir a dar suporte nativo o meu interesse por ela cresceu.

Assim, quais são as principais diferenças entre elas? O que o Kotlin pode oferecer/resolver/melhorar em relação ao Java?

Comment: Sei que docs são ruins e tals, mas o máximo que eu conseguiria fazer é traduzir, porém eu não garanto a tradução, então vou apenas postar o link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html

Comment: Este [post](https://blog.philipphauer.de/idiomatic-kotlin-best-practices/) aborda alguns dos aspectos em relação ao que "o Kotlin pode oferecer/resolver/melhorar em relação ao Java"

Comment: As respostas parecem que estão ficando defasadas, né? Java começou ter algumas coisas e tem algumas que vão ter um breve.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Principais diferenças:

- Em Kotlin [funções](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) são `first-class citizens`, ou seja, a linguagem permite manipular funções com as principais, se não todas, operações disponíveis para outras entidades: passagem de argumentos, retorno de funções, modificações, atribuição de variáveis, etc... Isso nos permite utilizar alguns conceitos da programação funcional como: funcões puras, funções sem efeitos colaterais; funções de alta ordem, que tomam funções como parâmetro, como retorno, ou como ambas; imutabilidade, onde estados internos permanecem inalterados, incluindo as próprias `collections` da linguagem.

Exemplo 1:

```
fun callAction(action: (String) -> Unit) = action("Hello world!")
fun printMessage() = callAction { text -> println(text) }
printMessage()
```

Exemplo 2:

```
// Ou utilizando a referência do método
fun callAction(action: (String) -> Unit) = action("Hello world!")
fun printMessage() = callAction(::println)
printMessage()
```

- Kotlin suporta [notação infixa](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation), que é bem comum em [aritmética e na lógica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_infixa), onde os operadores são colocados entre os operandos em que eles atuam.

Exemplo:

```
infix fun Int.plus(text: String): Int = this + text.toInt()

println(1 plus "2")

// é o mesmo que
println(1.plus("2"))
```

- Kotlin suporta [funções de extensão](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), que nos dão a habilidade de extender uma classe com uma nova funcionalidade sem ter que herdar dela, ou usar qualquer tipo de padrão de projetos como [Decorator](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator).

Exemplo:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
fun Int.toBigDecimal() = BigDecimal(this)
println(4.toBigDecimal())
```

- Kotlin suporta [sobrecarga de operadores](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html), que nos permite fornecer implementações para um conjunto predefinido de operadores em nossos tipos. Lista completa de operadores pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html).

Exemplo:

```
data class Money(var value: Int)

operator fun Money.plusAssign(value: Money) {
    this.value += value.value
}

val money = Money(10)
money += Money(20)

println(money.value) // 30
```

- Kotlin possui [data-classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), semelhante as [case-classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) em Scala, o que facilita a criação de classes que muitas vezes servem apenas para armazenar dados como [DTO's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) ou [POJO's](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Objects). Nesse caso o compilador irá derivar os membros declarados no construtor primário e implementar: `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` e `copy`. Com elas podemos [desestruturar declarações](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes-and-destructuring-declarations), semelhante a [destructuring assignment](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) do ECMAScript6. Podemos também identificar padrões com `data-classes` utilizando o [pattern-matching](https://kotlin.link/articles/Kotlin-for-Scala-Developers.html) da linguagem.

Exemplo:

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)

val jane = User("Jane", 35) 
val (name, age) = jane // destructuring declaration
println("$name, $age years of age") // prints "Jane, 35 years of age"
```

- Kotlin possui [sealed-classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html), que são usadas para representar hierarquias de classes restritas, quando um valor pode ter um dos tipos de um conjunto limitado, mas não pode ter qualquer outro tipo. Eles são, em certo sentido, uma extensão de classes enumeradas: o conjunto de valores para um tipo enum também é restrito, mas cada constante enum existe apenas como uma única instância, enquanto uma subclasse de uma classe selada pode ter múltiplas instâncias que podem conter estado.

Exemplo:

```
sealed class Expression {
    data class Const(val number: Double) : Expression()
    data class Sum(val e1: Expression, val e2: Expression) : Expression()
    object NotANumber : Expression()
}

fun eval(expr: Expression): Double = when (expr) {
    is Expression.Const -> expr.number
    is Expression.Sum -> eval(expr.e1) + eval(expr.e2)
    Expression.NotANumber -> Double.NaN
}
```

- Kotlin trata a [nulidade de campos](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) em seu próprio sistema de tipos, nos auxiliando a tratar valores nulos apenas quando preciso, e evitando erros de referência nula, também conhecido como o [erro de um bilhão de dólares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions).

Exemplo:

```
val x: String  = ""
val y : String?  = null

println(x.length) // 0
println(y?.length) // null

y?.let(::println) // println não é chamado porque y é nulo
```

**Notas:**

- Em resumo, Kotlin nos permite a implementação de conceitos do paradigma de Programação Orientada a Objetos quanto de Programação Funcional, nos permitindo extrair o melhor dos dois mundos, com uma linguagem concisa e ainda assim incrivelmente poderosa.
- Sendo um pouco pragmático, tudo o que se faz com Kotlin pode ser feito com Java, em relação a funcionalidades, mas acredito que Kotlin se torna melhor em relação a praticidade, simplicidade e produtividade.
- Para quem tiver interesse em aprender a linguagem, existe o [Kotlin Koans](https://try.kotlinlang.org) onde são passados alguns desafios e você tem de fazê-los.
- Site de documentação da linguagem: kotlinlang.org
- Documento de especificação da linguagem: kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf

Além dos pontos citados, há vários outros conceitos que são interessantes, mas que não coloquei aqui para não me extender mais.

- [Class Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html)
- [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)
- [Delegated Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html)
- [Visibility Modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html)
- [Generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html)
- [Nested Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html)
- [Returns and Jumps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html)

Comment: Essa resposta tá incrível. Parabéns!

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente o kotlin tráz diversas funcionalidades em comparação ao java, segundo o site oficial ela é mais concisa, reduzindo o código em até 40% comparado ao java, kotlin tem um paradigma de linguagem funcional, suporta a passagem de funções como parâmetros de métodos, lambda nativo, dentre outras. de acordo também com o site é uma linguagem mais segura, possui os tipos não anuláveis presentes em outras linguagens como o Swift, que evita as exceções que temos em tempo de execução no java ao utilizar referências nulas.

é uma linguagem nova que traz um novo fôlego para desenvolvedores Android que a tanto tempo utilizam o java, a comunidade está animada com o trabalho da JetBrains, para os programadores java é bem curta a curva de aprendizado. este é basicamente o resumo sobre o kotlin, você pode encontrar mais informações no site oficial.

http://kotlinlang.org/