# Desempenho Kotlin vs java e vale a pena trocar o java pelo Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

O desempenho de execução no android (me refiro a velocidade do aplicativo e não a velocidade de compilação, pois benchmarks em maquinas potentes mostraram o kotlin mais lento que o java em termos de compilação) do kotlin é mais rápido e eficiente?

Estive pensando em abandonar o java e aprender kotlin, mas não sei se vale a pena, um dos maiores motivos para querer aprender foi a briga da oracle com o google em questões de direitos autorais por usarem a linguagem deles, tanto que agora a linguagem oficial do android é kotlin.

Comment: Qual a real importância que tem o tempo de compilação?

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as principais diferenças entre Kotlin e Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205914/2541)

Comment: Me refiro ao tempo de execução, mas para mim pode importar por que um app meu conseguiu quebrar um recorde de demora de compilação para 20 minutos neste domingo mesmo usando paralel e daemon no android studio

Comment: Kotlin é UMA linguagem oficial do Android, não A oficial. A adição foi feita tendo em mente a interoperabilidade com o Java.

Comment: [@piovezan Gostaria de acrescentar que as novas bibliotecas estão sendo escritas em Kotlin somente, como por exemplo, Jetpack Compose.](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Olá,

Trabalho com Kotlin no Android há aproximadamente um ano e meio. Já utilizei a linguagem em diversos aplicativos, alguns escritos parcialmente em Kotlin e parcialmente em Java, e outros escritos totalmente em Kotlin.

Sobre a performance da linguagem durante o tempo de execução no Android, não existem diferenças significativas em relação à linguagem Java. Seu aplicativo não ficará nem mais rápido e nem mais lento por utilizar Kotlin.

Existem, porém, vários outros ganhos em utilizar Kotlin ao invés de Java, que vão desde a qualidade do seu código até a manutenção mais fácil no futuro. Além disso, Kotlin acelera o desenvolvimento, pois a linguagem aumenta a sua produtividade.

Para mais informações, por favor, dê uma olhada neste artigo que escrevi: https://medium.com/movile-tech/trocar-o-java-pelo-kotlin-8bed76014d99

Comment: Você tem algum livro de kotlin que poderia recomendar?