# @Autowired service não funciona no ConstraintValidator em Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, restful, controller, kotlin

Já uso Spring Boot há algum tempo em Java e nunca tive problema com injeções usando o @Autowired. Mas recentemente resolvi transformar um projeto de API Rest que estava em Java para o Kotlin, todo o código funcionou perfeitamente menos os meus ConstraintValidators que utilizo para validar os campos que chegam.

Segue o código em Kotlin:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = [CargoInsertValidator::class])
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
annotation class CargoInsert(
        val message: String = "Erro de validação",
        val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
        val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)

class CargoInsertValidator : ConstraintValidator<CargoInsert, Cargo> {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var cargoService: CargoService

    override fun initialize(constraintAnnotation: CargoInsert) {}

    override fun isValid(objDTO: Cargo, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean {
        // mais código
        val cargoNome: Cargo = cargoService.findByNome(objDTO.nome)
        // mais código
    }
}
```

Quando chega na linha em que chamo uma função do "cargoService" recebo o seguinte erro:

```
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='lateinit property cargoService has not been initialized'
```

Como dá pra ver, o spring não inicializa o cargoService para eu poder usá-lo. Mas isso só acontece nessa classe (que extende ConstraintValidator), pois em qualquer outra parte do projeto em que eu injeto o cargoService ele funciona perfeitamente. Lembrando que o código similar em Java funciona sem problemas. Já tentei anotar o CargoInsertValidator com @Component, @Service, @Configuration e nada.

Outro detalhe, o erro só ocorre quando eu tento inserir na tabela cargo durante a inicialização do spring, seja ela feito via CommandLineRunner ou criando um @Bean, o que acontece no profile de "test" quando quero iniciar o banco do zero e inserir alguns dados fictícios. Mas se eu não tentar inserir nada no início e deixar para inserir depois utilizando a API Rest em si ele funciona. Ou seja, em alguma hora essa injeção por @Autowired fica pronta, mas não quando eu preciso lá no começo, o que em Java não parecia ser problema.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que ocorre? Por que a injeção não é feita em Kotlin?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Quais as principais diferenças entre Kotlin e Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205914/quais-as-principais-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-kotlin-e-java)

Answer (score -1):

Depois de muita procura eu achei a solução na nessa resposta:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897856/13098285

Colocando a inicialização do meu banco de dados na classe StartHere todos os @Autowired já estavam prontos para serem usado.

Muito obrigado @Adrenal1ne